# sql server the select permission was denied on the object backupset?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, restore

I've created an MSSQL db from smarterasp.net. Now I'm connecting to it with SQL Server Management Systems, but once I right click database->Task->Restore DB, it print to me this:

[image]

I should be db_owner (Security->Users->dbo->Membership I've flag db_owner), but I can't load .bak file?

Comment: give permission db_backup operator  for login

Comment: @Chanukya: I cannot do it! It says "cannot use the special principal 'dbo'" :O

Comment: USE MyDataBase
EXEC sp_changedbowner 'sa', 'true' try like this

Comment: "Cannot find the principal 'sa', because it does not exist or you do not have permission." . But under Logins I have the user sa.

Comment: tell me ome thing are you db owner or not

Comment: I've created it using the panel control of smarterasp.net. It creates the db for me, giving the access. How can I check if I'm db owner or not? under Security->Logins or MyDatabase_NAME -> Security -> users -> dbo?

Answer (score 1):

Being a db_owner isn't enough access to restore a database. The db_owner permission can only be checked if the database is online but for restore if the database doesn't already exist there is no way for SQL Server to check what level of permissions you have on the database.

Therefore to be able to restore a database you will need to be a member of the default server role `dbcreator`.